# Why is moodle not available?

Tags: moodle

I configured moodle but I'm getting an error message:

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

My moodle directory is in `var/www/html/moodle` and in my `moodle/config.php` is `$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/moodledata';`

Still nothing works when I try to start moodle. What can be done about it?

Comment: Are you sure the directory `/var/moodledata` exists and is accessible by the server process?

Answer (score 6):

I think the moodledata folder does not have write permission. provide 0777 permission to the folder then it should be accessible.

Answer (score 3):

You should first create that directory and give access to the user that run the web server to this directory.
on centos/redhat:

```
chown apache.apache /var/moodledata
```

Note that on centos/redhat there is a good chance that SELINUX is blocking the web server process to access /var/moodledata directory.
The easy way to check it is to disable it (temporarily) by typing:

```
setenforce 0
service httpd restart
```

Then if in this way it works - set it to allow access to this directory and the re-enable it in this way:

```
setenforce 1
```

if you want to disable selinux completely, then edit /etc/selinux/config and set this line:

```
SELINUX=disabled
```

on debian/ubuntu the ownership should be like this:

```
chown www-data.www-data /var/moodledata
```

Answer (score 0):

Moodle does need to create and delete files within its working folder. If the folder owner is `Apache`, then you actually only need `700` permissions and can ignore the group. Otherwise you have to set `770` permissions to all directories in `moodledata` and `660` to all files in `moodledata` folder.

The critical thing is to make sure that the `moodledata` folder is NOT in any web accessible area (http root). If your http root is `/var/www/html`, then make it `/var/moodledata`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config.php file and check the $CFG->dataroot variable. it should have the absolute path to your Moodle data.

If dataroot is configured properly and moodle data exists then, run the below-mentioned command using command line.

chown -R www-data:www-data yourmoodledataname