# How to solve this error in moodle ? and setup in localhost?

Tags: http, localhost, moodle

Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Comment: Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please provide some code, what you are trying to do and what did you try to fix it ?

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378796/moodle-cfg-dataroot-is-not-configured-properly

Comment: This error or made by the localhost  (config.php)  file  in local setup

Comment: $CFG->wwwroot   = 'http://localhost/moodle';
$CFG->dataroot  = 'C:\\wamp64\\moodledata';
$CFG->admin     = 'admin';

Comment: $CFG->dbuser    = 'root';
$CFG->dbpass    = 'root';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is moodle not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31138846/why-is-moodle-not-available)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 'config.php' in your moodle installation files directory.

There you can find a line like below, which shows your directory name (it seems empty as per your error, you need to define path here) - in this directory/folder your moodle media uploads get store.

$CFG->dataroot  = '/var/moodledata';

Moreover, after define this you will require to give Read,Write,Execute permissions to this folder.

(here '/var...' mentioned as Ubuntu directory structure, in localhost you need to mention respectively)